# How to disable notice outputs in PHP?

Tags: php, debugging, output

I have a (local) webserver with a configuration to show all errors of PHP (since debugging is easier that way).

For some reason, there is a minor issue in the PHP files, resulting in errors like the following:

```
Notice: Constant ADODB_BAD_RS already defined in /full/path/to/adodb.inc.php on line 23
```

Since these notices are not interesting, at least for the library I'm including, I would like to ignore them somehow.

Currently I'm doing this the following way:

```
echo "<!-- Ignore some useless warning";
require_once "path/to/adodb.inc.php";
echo "End ignoring warning -->";
```

This works fine for my generated HTML, though *the warnings still appear in generated HTML code*.

Is there a way to remove those lines from the output, without having to sacrifice the possibility to see similar notices for my own code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sure you want to disable notices, then you can just put a `@` sign before `require_once` or before a other function that throws notices/errors.

Comment: The @sign does wonders!
Though, if I know have an error in the usage of that code (EDIT: e.g. when I write a mistake in arguments I give to a function defined in that file), it will still show, will it not?

Comment: Well the @ sign disables all messages of the function, where the @ sign is placed before, errors included. All other errors and notices will still be displayed.

Answer (score 4):

Using `error_reporting` you can achieve that.

```
error_reporting(0); // disable errors
require_once "path/to/adodb.inc.php";
error_reporting(E_ALL); //enable errors again
```

Comment: That's exactly what just adding `@` in front of the script would do.

Answer (score 3):

`error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` is the way to go.

This disables only notices.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is doing [**error_reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)(0), you could also use [**Output Control Functions**](http://www.php.net/manual/it/ref.outcontrol.php) but their use is a bit not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all warnings, you can set `display_errors` to `0` in your php.ini file for your web server. Or you can use the function `error_reporting()` and pass a `0` as well or whatever other options you may want. [Here is PHP's manual for error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)